# UIHint Binding Issue in MVC 4 using Kendo Popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to customize kendo datepicker using MVC 4 to show the selection as in form of "Day Month" (for ex. if we select today's date, it should be displayed as "16 August".

I achieved this as follows.

1.Added a View in Shared folder as follows

```
 // file Name is = SeasonDate.Html

@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
   .Name("monthpicker")
   .Start(CalendarView.Month)
   .Depth(CalendarView.Month)
   .Format("dd MMMM")
   .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:85%"})         
 )
```

2.Added a model with UIHINT as follows

```
public partial class classname
{
    [Display(Name = "Hi Season")]
    [UIHint("SeasonDate")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0}:d")]
    public DateTime? HiSeasonDate { get; set; }   
 }
```

3.My UI in kendo is as follows

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Model(m =>
   {
      m.Field(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.HiSeasonDate);
   }
 )
```

My question is, when i create a record i get proper formatted date and it's saved in DB as well.

But when i edit that row, the saved date does not get bind to kendo datepicker.

Please let me know your valuable thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have to think you've figured this out by now, but in case not...

You need to specify a model of DateTime in your template view. Then, use DatePickerFor() referencing the model. Such as

```
@model DateTime?

@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m)
    ... whatever other properties you need to set
)
```